# How to setup MySQL users with Maxscale

Tags: mariadb-10.4, maxscale

I'm setting up a 3 nodes (MariaDB 10.4) Galera cluster with 2 frontal servers.

Inside each of these frontal servers there is also a Maxscale 6 daemon.

```
[listener]
type=listener
service=readwritesplit
protocol=MariaDBClient
address=127.0.0.1
port=3306
```

**All of these servers are inside the `10.1.0.0/24` network.**

At MariaDB, I've created users like `CREATE USER 'user'@'10.1.0.%'` but these can't authenticate.

```
Authentication failed for user 'user'@[127.0.0.1] to service 'readwritesplit'. Originating listener: 'listener'. MariaDB error: 'Access denied for user 'user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)'.
```

So I've `RENAME 'user'@'10.1.0.%' TO 'user'@'127.0.0.1'`. Another authentication error.

```
maxscale[1109436]: Authentication to 'node1' failed: 1045, #28000: Access denied for user 'user'@'frontal1' (using password: YES)
```

I ended up to `RENAME 'user'@'10.1.0.%' TO 'user'@'%'`. All fine here of course.

As long as all servers are on the `10.1.0.%` network, why users `'user'@'10.1.0.%'` can't authenticate?

Comment: What version of MaxScale are you using?

Comment: @markusjm As specified in main thread, Maxscale 6 (6.1.4).

Comment: Ah, my apologies: I am blinder than usual :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access from the local host (i.e. `127.0.0.1`), you either need two separate users (`'user'@'127.0.0.1'` and `'user'@'10.1.0.%'`) or a grant that covers them both (`'user'@'%'`). A more detailed description of this can be found in the [MaxScale tutorial](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-setting-up-mariadb-maxscale/#creating-client-user-accounts).

You can make authentication handling with MaxScale significantly simpler by using the [`proxy_protocol`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-6-mariadb-maxscale-configuration-guide/#proxy_protocol) feature in MaxScale. This would allow you to define users only once with the exact IP address they come from and let the [`proxy-protocol-networks`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#proxy_protocol_networks) variable in MariaDB control which MaxScale instances are allowed to act as proxies.

---

The error `'user'@'127.0.0.1'` means that the client was attempting to connect from the local host, i.e. by connecting to the loopback address. This isn't covered by the `10.1.0.%` host which explains why it failed.

Having converted the user to `'user'@'127.0.0.1'`, the local login between the client and MaxScale worked but then the backend server rejected the authentication as the MaxScale host no longer matches the grant's network (`127.0.0.1`).

Using the `%` host causes all addresses to match which explains why it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but can `proxy_protocol` be used here? As maxscale resides on the same host than the client (this is why it is listening at `127.0.0.1`), won't the passed IP be `127.0.0.1`?

If yes, can in this case the `'user'@'127.0.0.1'` be used?

Comment: Yes, you can still use `proxy_protocol` even if you log in from the localhost. It simply removes the need to create a second user with the MaxScale IP address. You do still need to create the `'user'@'127.0.0.1'´ user to be able to log in.